# How to avoid using useSelector hook many times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I am having a trouble with decoupling business logic and ui. I am new to react. I know that my component contains too much responsibilities. Also i am not sure if it is a good idea to use a lot of variables with useSelector hook, but i dont know hot to avoid it. Please can someone explain how to fix it or give some adviсe what should to read/watch?

```
    const Catalog = () => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const items = useSelector(state => state.catalog.plantsList);
        const isFetching = useSelector(state => state.catalog.isFetching);
        const currentPage = useSelector(state => state.catalog.currentPage);
        const totalCount = useSelector(state => state.catalog.totalCount);
        const limitItems = useSelector(state => state.catalog.limitItems);
        const pagesCount = Math.ceil(totalCount/limitItems);
        const pages = [];
        createPages(pages, pagesCount, currentPage);

        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(fetchData(currentPage, limitItems));
        }, [currentPage]);

        let plantItems = items.map(p => <PlantItem key={p.id} id={p.id} image={p.image} name={p.name}
                                                   cost={p.cost}/>)
        return (
            <div className={s.catalog}>
                <p className={s.catalog__description}>Сдавая пластик в пункты приема, Вы получаете природные баллы. За один
                    килограмм пластика можно получить
                    10 природных баллов.</p>
                <div className={ isFetching === false ? s.catalog__list : s.fetching }>
                    {
                        isFetching === false ?
                            plantItems
                            :
                            <Preloader/>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={s.catalog__pages}>
                    {pages.map((page, index) => <div
                        key={index}
                        className={currentPage == page ? s.currentPage : s.page}
                        onClick={() => dispatch(setCurrentPage(page))}>{page}</div>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not do what the other answers here suggest: `useSelector(state => state.catalog)` will update your component whenever `state.catalog.anythingUnrelated` updates, even if you only need `state.catalog.a`, `state.catalog.b` and `state.catalog.c` in your component.
You would be oversubscribing and your app would be rerendering a lot more often than necessary.

Always selectively subscribe to the data you actually need. Calling `useSelector` a few more times is totally fine and generally more performant than oversubscribing. (we even [recommend doing that in the style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#call-useselector-multiple-times-in-function-components))

As an alternative, you can also move calculation of important data from the component into the selector and create a memoized selector. That will not be a lot less code, but it will move it out of the component. Read [Deriving Data with Selectors](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors) on that.

Or you use a non-memoized selector in combination with a [custom comparison function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates), like this:

```js
const {
   plantsList: items,
   isFetching,
   currentPage,
   totalCount,
   limitItems
} = useSelector(({catalog}) => ({
   plantsList: catalog.plantsList,
   isFetching: catalog.isFetching,
   currentPage: catalog.currentPage,
   totalCount: catalog.totalCount,
   limitItems: catalog.limitItems
}), shallowEqual);
```

but as you see that's not a lot less code either.

In the end: it's just fine to have multiple `useSelector` calls.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at your example, you can use de-structure property. Something like this:

```
const {
   plantsList: items,
   isFetching,
   currentPage,
   totalCount,
   limitItems
} = useSelector(state => state.catalog);
```

Comment: It'll cause unnecessary re-render. See https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#call-useselector-multiple-times-in-function-components